# Django 1.3 on WSGI unable to resolve mysql host

Tags: mysql, linux, django, apache, wsgi

We have a Django system that has been running on RunServer for some time. It is about time it was running WSGI, and at some point we may move to a less arcane version too (assume this is not easy or the modifications/downtime required are currently not an option). This is all on a Linux host, and for the WSGI configuration, served through Apache.

In trying to convert to WSGI we are hitting a problem. The settings file that works perfectly on the same server, albeit as root, using ./manage.py runserver, now will not work as the apache user that I presume a WSGI configuration will run as. The httpd worker threads are owned by the apache user.

It is complaining in the log:

```
OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'ourserver.ourdomain.com' (111)")
```

Real server names have been changed here. This is the same server, the same Django app, but it can not lookup the same hostname. Django is serving my pages - but as soon as any tries to use the models, this is making it break.

I can even su to that apache user, perform an nslookup for the host - and it will resolve.

- Distribution: Fedora15, x86_64.
- Apache: httpd 2.2.22 1.fc15
- mod_wsgi: 3.2 3.fc15

Comment: Further information - when this occurs, other than httpd error log, I see nothing in /var/log/secure, /var/log/messages or dmesg.

Comment: The distribution in use (again assume changing it is a very expensive option), is Fedora15, x86_64.

Comment: This works if I use the IP address. There are places where it must connect to other DB servers - I will try those parts of the system.

Comment: No they (implemented with mysqldb functions and not django models) aren't able to lookup via hostname either. I am currently suspecting some kind of hostname restriction, or environment setting.

Comment: I hate to be a pest, but if you're using Django 1.3 in 2015, your site is open to many vulnerabilities. The last patch to Django 1.3 was on Feb 21, 2013. There have been countless vulnerabilities in the 2+ years since.

Comment: The site is purely internal. We will update - but the move to a WSGi server is essential first. If it was publicly facing and running with RunServer it would be vulnerable even on the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this. It is all to do with permissions and restrictions when running as the Apache user which is restricted, including in ways that prevent some types of socket being opened.

The answer is to use the WSGI Daemon mode.
This stuff:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
```

Will not let you do it. So you need to add the additional parts. Inside the VirtualHost section for your site (presuming you have one):

```
WSGIDaemonProcess process_group_name
WSGIProcessGroup process_group_name 
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=process_group_name
```

Be warned documentation may make you think the process group name is your hostname, or virtual hostname - it is not. A site-name for the Django site deployed made more sense to me. Also you may find connection issues with the WSGI stuff, so outside of the VirtualHost section, add a location for the WSGI sockets:

```
WSGISocketPrefix  /var/run/wsgi
```

All the socket access now works.